# Any difference in using an empty interface or an empty struct as a map's value?

Tags: go

I am using this construct to simulate a set

```
type MyType uint8
map[MyType]interface{}
```

I then add in all my keys and map them to `nil`.

I've learnt that it is also possible to use

```
map[MyType]struct{}
```

Any benefits of using the empty struct versus `interface{}`.

Comment: Checkout this article on the empty struct: http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Memory usage. For example, types `struct{}`, `interface{}`, and `bool`,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var s struct{}
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(s))
    var i interface{}
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(i))
    var b bool
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(b))
}
```

Output (bytes for 32-bit architecture):

```
0
8
1
```

Output (bytes for 64-bit architecture):

```
0
16
1
```

References:

[Go Data Structures: Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Comment: How does this affect the memory usage of the map? What will it allocate internally for a struct{} type for the values?

Comment: @DanielWilliams: A Go map stores key and element values. A `struct{}` element value occupies zero bytes.

Comment: I guess that leads into what happens with a `map[struct{}]struct{}`? It would have a zero sized key and a zero sized value but you could put 1 thing it (also zero sized).

Comment: @DanielWilliams: Use type `bool` instead of type `map`.

Answer (score 41):

The empty struct and empty interface, though syntactically similar, are actually opposites. An empty struct holds **no** data; an empty interface can hold **any** type of value. If I see a `map[MyType]struct{}`, I know immediately that no values will be stored, only keys. If I see a `map[MyType]interface{}`, my first impression will be that it is a heterogenous collection of values. Even if I see code storing nil in it, I won't know for sure that some other piece of code doesn't store something else in it.

In other words, using `struct{}` makes your code much more readable. It also saves a little memory, as described in the other answer, but that is just a fringe benefit of using the right tool for the job.

Comment: What about `map[MyType]bool`?

Comment: I would actually tend to use `map[MyType]bool` myself, because it can be used directly in an `if` condition, and it would probably produce the most readable code. But the OP only asked about `struct` and `interface`, and I wanted to keep my answer simple. (And `map[MyType]struct{}` is a recognized idiom for sets.)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add additional detail about empty struct , as differences are already covered by andybalholm and peterSO .

Below is the example which shows usability of empty struct .

> Creates an instance of rectangle struct by using a pointer address
>   operator is denoted by & symbol.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type rectangle struct {
    length  int
    breadth int
    color   string
}

func main() {
    var rect1 = &rectangle{10, 20, "Green"} // Can't skip any value
    fmt.Println(rect1)

    var rect2 = &rectangle{}
    rect2.length = 10
    rect2.color = "Red"
    fmt.Println(rect2) // breadth skipped

    var rect3 = &rectangle{}
    (*rect3).breadth = 10
    (*rect3).color = "Blue"
    fmt.Println(rect3) // length skipped
}
```

Reference : https://www.golangprograms.com/go-language/struct.html

For a thorough read you can refer : https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct