# Inlining and output binary size

Tags: go

```
package main

type TreeCell struct {
    Tabs func() *string
}

func Cell() *string {
    s:= ""
    return &s
}

func Table(Line *[]TreeCell) {
    if Line != nil {
        Num["rtt"] = Line
    }
}

var (
    Num map[string]*[]TreeCell 
)

func main() {

    Table(&[]TreeCell{
        TreeCell{Tabs: Cell},
        TreeCell{Tabs: Cell},
        ...repeat 15000 times
        TreeCell{Tabs: Cell},
    })
}
```

go build -a -v -gcflags "-N -l" -ldflags "-s -w"

Size of executable file 1,9Mb

```
__text              1459891   16781312
__rodata             158107   18241216
Total               1951521
```

if I change the `func() *string` to the `interface{}`

```
type TreeCell struct {
    Tabs interface{}
}
```

then size of executable file 32Mb

```
__text               1864389   16781312
__rodata            30375699   18645728
Total               32698219
```

Why?

Go version 1.9.2

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770114/any-difference-in-using-an-empty-interface-or-an-empty-struct-as-a-maps-value-i

Comment: __text (code) increased by only 404Kb. 404kb / ~15000 =~ 28 byte pro TreeCell{Tabs: Cell}. I believe that abnormally increased __rodata (data)

Comment: I think it would be better if you change the header of your question to underline that the question is about size of result binary file.

Answer (score 0):

The size of an `interface{}` variable is 8 or 16 bytes (depending on the architecture being 32 or 64 bit), and the size of a function variable is either 4 or 8 bytes. So there is only a 2 multiplication which would not explain the big difference in the output binary (15.000 * 8 bytes is only 120 KB).

What you experience is the result of *different inlining* compiler optimization. The function `Cell()` is very simple and is eligible for inlining.

### When inlining is disabled

If we include the `-gcflags '-N -l'` params like in your example (these flags tell the compiler to disable inlining), then references to `Cell` are not inlined, so using `func() *string` will only use a 4-byte function pointer.

Using `interface{}` however will result in *inlining* `Cell` values. Interface values hold a copy, and the function call is not inlined, but when the function value is used when implicitly wrapped in `interface{}` values, it is inlined (duplicated). In each time, that is 15.000 times! So basically the `Cell()` function body is included 15.000 times. Now that's big, that is what makes the resulting binary 30 MB.

### When inlining is enabled

If we exclude the `-gcflags '-N -l'` params, **it's actually the opposite**: the compiled binary is about 2 MB when using `interface{}`, and it's about 30 MB when using `func () *string`.

This time when using the `Cell` function value in the composite literal for initializing the `TreeCell.Tabs` field, the compiler will inline the `Cell()` function in all 15.000 times! When using `interface{}`, the function bodies will not be inlined however. Not sure why, a possible explanation is that it is also inlined in case of `interface{}`, and since interface values are immutable, the same value is used 15.000 times.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Why does the size __rodata increase and not __text?

Comment: @AndreyVoronko Why would `__text` increase and not `__rodata`? Function body is duplicated 15.000 times, that is not text but code.

Comment: `__text` is code. `__rodata` is readonly data (constant, strings e.t.c )
Flags `-l` (disable inline) does not affect the result. Only `-N`

Comment: @AndreyVoronko Then you answered it: `__text` is code, and that is being duplicated by inlining.

Comment: I think that this is not inline. If this would be inline, then increasing the inline function's code would increase the size of the executable file.
I changed the code
`func Cell() *string {
 s:= "01234567890102345678901234567890123456789012345678900123456789010234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
 return &s
}`
but the size remained the same

Comment: @AndreyVoronko Your change does not result in bigger binary because that string literal (constant) is only stored once in the binary.

Comment: I tried the same func Cell() *string {
 s:= ""
 fmt.Println("sdsdsdsd")
 return &s
}

Comment: Ok. If it is inline. 30MB / 15000 = 2KB I think it's a lot for func Cell() *string {
 s:= ""
 return &s
}