# Is there a more efficient way to handle string escaping in this function?

Tags: go

I'm migrating some existing code from another language. In the following function it's more or less a 1-1 migration, but given the newness of the language to me I'd like to know if there's better / more efficient ways to handle how the escaped string gets built:

```
func influxEscape(str string) string {
    var chars = map[string]bool{
        "\\": true,
        "\"": true,
        ",":  true,
        "=":  true,
        " ":  true,
    }

    var escapeStr = ""

    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        var char = string(str[i])

        if chars[char] == true {
            escapeStr += "\\" + char
        } else {
            escapeStr += char
        }
    }

    return escapeStr
}
```

This code performs escaping to make string values compatible with the InfluxDB line protocol.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since the code is already working.

Comment: Also there's already an InfluxDB Go client - it's the top-tier client as InfluxDB itself is written in Go.

Comment: You can get a **very slight** memory usage improvement (and more important, more readable code) by using `struct{}` in place of `bool` in your map keys. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770744/13860).

Comment: @Flimzy in regards to your comment on `"\\"`, the first backslash is an escape for the second. The compiler throws a syntax error without it.

Comment: @Flimzy and mkopriva +1 for backticks

Comment: before worrying about performance, worry about correctness. then consider you are 1/ allocating 2/ converting. if you want something, like this, to be as performant as possible, you, simply, must execute as few ops as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it needs too much room for that.

One more thing to consider—which I mentioned in [a comment on Burak Serdar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040283/1256452)—is what happens when your input string is not valid UTF-8.

Remember that a Go string is a [*byte sequence*](https://blog.golang.org/strings).  It need not be valid Unicode.  It *may* be intended to *represent* valid Unicode, or it may not.  For instance, it could be ISO-Latin-1 or something else that might not play well with UTF-8.

If it *is* non-UTF-8, using a `range` loop on it will translate each invalid sequence to the invalid rune.  (See the linked Go blog post.)  If it is *intended* to be valid UTF-8, this may be a plus, and of course, you can check for the resulting [`RuneError`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/).

Your original loop leaves characters above ASCII DEL (127 or 0x7f) alone.  If the bytes in the string *are* something like ISO-Latin-1, this may be the correct behavior.  If not, you may be passing invalid, un-sanitized input to this other program.  If you are deliberately sanitizing input, you must find out what kind of input it expects, and do a complete job of sanitizing input.

(I still have scars from being forced to cope with a really poor XML encoder coupled to an old database from some number of jobs ago, so I tend to be extra-cautious here.)

Comment: Following up on this, I've spent the last hour or so digging into the encoding problem some more. Is there a relatively straightforward way to always force-encode a string to utf8? Have been looking at this https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding

Comment: I don't know what's actually *good*, but having just glanced over the doc at your link, that looks like a sensible approach. It's similar to what Python3 does with codecs.

Answer (score 2):

This should be somewhat equivalent to your code:

```
out := bytes.Buffer{}
for _, x := range str {
  if strings.IndexRune(`\",= `, x)!=-1 {
     out.WriteRune('\\')
  }
  out.WriteRune(x)
}
return out.String()
```

Comment: But is it more efficient? (Of course, a benchmark is the only way to know)

Comment: It will be _non_-equivalent if the input string is not valid UTF-8. The `range` loop will change "bad" input bytes to the invalid rune. It's not clear whether this should be considered a feature. :-)

Comment: True. If speed is concern, IndexRune can be replaced with an if statement, but using a buffer should be more efficient in general.

Comment: @Geuis that's subjective.

Comment: @torek the original algorithm is broken if the input has multibyte characters.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: we can't know that for sure (well, not without knowing what this other InfluxDB stuff is). See my answer (which technically should be a comment, and which I'm still writing).